# how to filter dictionary based on their value character swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

i have to filter dictionary  containing my text inside of textfield
//my code

```
var arrayData = [["Name":"Sahil"],["Name":"Raman"],["Name":"ashish"],["Name":"Vishnu"],["Name":"Deep"],["Name":"sahil"],["Name":"Swift"]]
```

```
//my result should be  like this
[["Name":"Sahil"],["Name":"ashish"],["Name":"Vishnu"],["Name":"Swift"]]
```

Comment: i have  to get values containing letter "s"

Comment: Sorry  i don’t  know how to stack overflow and please don’t  decrease my post

Comment: let  filteredArray = arrayData.filter({$0["Name"] == textField.text})

Comment: It will keep only the values where the Name value is "s". You might want to use `contains()` instead... Edit your question with your attempt, and especially saying that the logic with the "s", because without that it was unclear.

Comment: filteredArray = arrayData.filter({$0["Name"]?.contains(textField.text!) as! Bool})

Comment: And what are the output of your attempts? For case sensitive, I didn't see it at first, you need to use to use the `compare()` method with the case insentitive option.

Comment: [["Name": "ashish"], ["Name": "Vishnu"], ["Name": "sahil"]] this is output

Comment: but i am missing two names in my output

Comment: `let filteredArray = arrayData.filter { $0["Name"]?.range(of: "s", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }` I meant `range(of:options:)` instead of `compare()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was unclear, you explained it later in comments, but you want to keep the values for key `"Name"` which contains an "s" case insensitive.

Let's add a couple of additional values to show why your previous attempts failed:

```
var arrayData = [["Name":"Sahil"],
                 ["Name":"Raman"],
                 ["Name":"ashish"],
                 ["Name":"Vishnu"],
                 ["Name":"Deep"],
                 ["Name":"sahil"],
                 ["Name":"Swift"],
                 ["Name":"s"],
                 ["Name":"S"]]
```

And simplify:

```
let searchText = "s" // textField.text ?? ""
```

You attempted:

```
let filteredArray1 = arrayData.filter { $0["Name"] == searchText }
print(filteredArray1)
```

Output:

```
$> [["Name": "s"]]
```

So, you get only when value is exactly equals to `"s"`, that's normal, you are using `==`

You then attempted:

```
let filteredArray2 = arrayData.filter { $0["Name"]!.contains(searchText) }
print(filteredArray2)
```

Output:

```
$>[["Name": "ashish"], ["Name": "Vishnu"], ["Name": "sahil"], ["Name": "s"]]
```

So, you are getting anyvalues when it has a `"s"` inside it. It's almost that, but you aren't getting when it has an uppercase `"S"`.
To do that, you can use `range(of:options:searchRange:local:)` with `.caseInsensitive` optiono. If the result isn't `nil`, it means it has been found.

So you can use:

```
let filteredArray3 = arrayData.filter { $0["Name"]?.range(of: "s", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
print(filteredArray3)
```

Output:

```
$>[["Name": "Sahil"], ["Name": "ashish"], ["Name": "Vishnu"], ["Name": "sahil"], ["Name": "Swift"], ["Name": "s"], ["Name": "S"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var arrayDataFiltered = arrayData.filter { $0["Name"]?.lowercased().contains("s") ?? false }
```

Here is the documentation for filtering:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter

Comment: this one is also right